# Azure App Service - instances in three availability zones

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, load-balancing

I want to have three instances of my app service. Everyone should be in the other AZ, traffic between instances should be load balanced. How can I achieve it in the simplest way? Should I use ASE and create App Service Plan with 3 workers? But will it put my instances in other zones automatically? In near future I'll probably need to get these 3 instances behind reverse proxy - it should expose only one public IP Address and then balance it between 3 instances. Additionally I have there Azure Database connected to these three instances.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the closest answer to your question is to deploy your Azure App Service in an ILB App Service Environments as ASE can be deployed into Availability Zones (AZ).

If you pin your ILB ASE to a specific AZ, the resources used by an ILB ASE will either be pinned to the specified AZ or deployed in a zone redundant manner. Zonal ILB ASEs must be created using ARM templates with the new `zones` property.

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/zone-redundancy
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview